# Wit.ai bot with multiple languages

Tags: wit.ai

I plan on creating a bot that supports multiple languages and I've decided to do this with the wit.ai platform due to the many languages it supports.
The bot will use a webhook to detect the intent.

In Dialogflow it's possible to create 1 bot and add multiple languages to it. However, this doesn't seem to be the case with wit.ai. Am I correct in that I'll have to create 1 bot per language?

There must be some other more efficient way to accomplish this...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems not possible to add multiple languages to one instance of bot on wit.ai platform. 
Here is a closed old [issue](https://github.com/wit-ai/wit/issues/5) on GitHub saying that one instance per one language has to be made on wit.ai